# GPIO problems, when run infinitely goes to the right

Tags: gpio, python

I'm trying to get a controller to move right, preferably one space, using GPIO. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong but whenever I run the script it moves to the right but it never stops. I don't know if sleeps not working right or if I'm needing to be using BOARD instead of BCM but I'm at a loss.

I've tried to have the GPIO.output in a while loop not in a while loop. I've tried to have the GPIO.output(22, 0) outside of the while loop. I've tried making the sleep time larger and smaller than 1. I just really hope someone can help me. Sorry if the formatting is terrible, this is my first time posting. Thank you in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from time import sleep
import os
import pdb

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#right
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)

DIRECTION = input('Enter direction: ')

if DIRECTION == 'right':

    print("You picked right") 
    MOVE = eval(input('How many spaces do you want to move?: '))
    while MOVE > 0:
        GPIO.output(22, 1)
        sleep(1)
        MOVE = MOVE - 1
        print(MOVE)
        GPIO.output(22, 0)
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Could you tell what's `MOVE` behaving, what's the output of that `print`? ... and out of curiosity, what's that "controller" you're refering to?

Comment: What is pin 22 actually connected to? Just to be clean, it only starts moving to the right after typing `right` and that some number, or as soon as the scripts is started?

Comment: I'm trying to control a Wii U pro controller through computer inputs. Pin 22 is connected to the right directional contact on the controller. Yes, it only starts to move after I get how many spaces I would like to ideally move, which with sleep doesn't really work the way I'd like it to unless I can calculate how much sleep needs to be to move one space and then loop that, but that doesn't seem to work quite right either. MOVE is supposed to get how many times you want the cursor to move.

Comment: Sorry, this should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation. First, since you have used BCM numbering scheme, and you seem to be confused, check if you have connected to the right GPIO pin. In your case it will be physical pin 15. Second, If you have spare multimeter lying around, could you test the pin voltage when running the script? If you don't, attach an LED or something that can give you some indication as to what's the output of the pin. Each loop takes about 2 seconds. So just enter a number (enter 2) and test the pin (it will remain high for 4 seconds or thereabout in this cas

Comment: Some details of the circuit would be useful.  For instance why does setting gpio 22 high or low affect the controller?